# HTML/(pure)CSS - Animating a <select> dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I have this very basic dropdown menu using `select`. I'm using `select` because I'm going to need the `value` of the `weekday` object in a JS script. Is there any way I can make this animated? If that's not possible for the `select` tag, is there an other soultion where I can retain the `value` of the object? Thank you!

```css
#weekday {
 transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
```

```html
<select id="weekday">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the weekday</option>
  <option value="0">Monday</option>
  <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="3">Thursday</option>
  <option value="4">Friday</option>
  <option value="5">Saturday</option>
  <option value="6">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Animated how? What do you want that transition to actually do? Affect the speed the dropdown shows?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, I think he wants that select area to appear "slowly", but it is not gonna happen. 
@lte__ This is browser feature, you can change very little things with standard select tag. If you want custom markup, style and animation you should use some kind of ``selectmenu`` plugins (e.x , jqeury selectmenu) or write it yourself

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Any kind of animation. As you can see in the fiddle, transitioning doesn't work on it. Guess it wont as per lomboboo...

Comment: Is there any other way, fe. to use `<a>` tag, but retain the `value` functionality?